# Why am I getting only one row returned from a JOIN in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Why does the code below only return one row? I'm trying to add a JOIN query to this.

```
$invoices = Invoice::orderBy('invoices.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('invoice');
```

The above code works well, but it returns only one row when I add the JOIN. Why?

```
$invoices = Invoice::join('statuses', 'statuses.invoice_no', '=', 'invoices.invoice')
    ->orderBy('invoices.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('invoice');
```

Comment: Could it be that there is only one row that when JOINed like that meets the join criteria

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes seems so its like grabbing only the last data

Comment: Look at your database. Apply that JOIN logic and see how many rows you think should be returned, Have you done that? Are you sure there should be more than one row returned?

Comment: dont worry sir was able to fix it found out i saved only one invoice_no thats why

Comment: Hmm, thats what I was suggesting might be the issue

Comment: Please just delete the question as it is of no use to others, adding an answer like that is really not helpful

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it found out i saved only one invoice_no thats why... Thanks